Azure function - Nestjs Chunked HTML response
I have an Azure function where I am processing a large number files, I am aiming to send to progress messages to the browser in html to report on progress. I am using nextjs - below is the controller which works fine locally.
@Get('ping-html')
pingHTML(@Res() response: Response) {
    
    response.status(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT);
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    response.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');
    response.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
    const html = `<html><h1>Controller alive and kicking ...${moment().utc()}</h1>`;
    console.log(html);

    response.write(html);
    
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log('second time');
        response.write(`Second line after timeout ${moment().utc()}`);
        response.write("</body></html>")
        response.end();
        
    },10000)
    
    console.log(" response constructed ");
   return html;
}

But when deploy the code on Azure, it doesn't render the html and eventually times out with an error.
GET http://localhost:4000/api/ping-html net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 206 (Partial Content)

I have followed this blog / announcement
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/blog/appsonazureblog/azure-functions-support-for-http-streams-in-node-js-is-now-in-preview/4066575
main/index.ts:
import {  app, HttpRequest } from '@azure/functions';
export default function(context: any, req: HttpRequest): void {

  app.setup({ enableHttpStream: true })
  AzureHttpAdapter.handle(createApp, context, req);
  console.log("Deamon awake -- Azure Function started ...");
}

Any suggestions on resolving the above issue or alternatives of reporting progress from an Azure function. Thanks

Did you try increasing functionTimeout?

not facing a timeout issue, the sample function doesnt work even when i reduce setTimeout to a second

I have created a NestJs serverless Azure function to process large number files.
main/index.ts:
import { app, HttpRequest } from '@azure/functions';
import { AzureHttpAdapter } from '@nestjs/azure-func-http';
import { createApp } from 'src/main.azure';
export default function(context: any, req: HttpRequest): void {

  app.setup({ enableHttpStream: true })
  AzureHttpAdapter.handle(createApp, context, req);
  console.log("Deamon awake -- Azure Function started ...");
}

src/app.controller.ts:
import { Controller, Get, HttpStatus, Res } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
  @Get('ping-html')
  pingHTML(@Res() response: Response) {
    
    response.status(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT);
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    response.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');
    response.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
    const html = `<html><h1>Controller alive and kicking ...${moment().utc()}</h1>`;
    console.log(html);

    response.write(html);
    
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log('second time');
        response.write(`Second line after timeout ${moment().utc()}`);
        response.write("</body></html>")
        response.end();
        
    },10000)
    
    console.log(" response constructed ");
   return html;
}
}

Console Output:
Functions:

        main:  http://localhost:7071/api/{*segments}

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-11-26T08:10:36.060Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-11-26T08:10:46.723Z] Executing 'Functions.main' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=34326561-d942-4115-af77-3f3035384d95)
[2024-11-26T08:10:47.154Z] Deamon awake -- Azure Function started ...
[2024-11-26T08:10:47.173Z] [Nest] 9868  - 11/26/2024, 1:40:47 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[2024-11-26T08:10:47.190Z] [Nest] 9868  - 11/26/2024, 1:40:47 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +36ms
[2024-11-26T08:10:47.196Z] [Nest] 9868  - 11/26/2024, 1:40:47 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/api}: +6ms
[2024-11-26T08:10:47.199Z] [Nest] 9868  - 11/26/2024, 1:40:47 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api, GET} route +4ms
[2024-11-26T08:10:47.202Z] [Nest] 9868  - 11/26/2024, 1:40:47 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/ping-html, GET} route +1ms
[2024-11-26T08:10:47.206Z] [Nest] 9868  - 11/26/2024, 1:40:47 PM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +5ms
[2024-11-26T08:10:47.212Z] <html><h1>Controller alive and kicking ...Tue Nov 26 2024 08:10:47 GMT+0000</h1>
[2024-11-26T08:10:47.216Z]  response constructed
[2024-11-26T08:10:57.218Z] second time
[2024-11-26T08:10:57.341Z] Executed 'Functions.main' (Succeeded, Id=34326561-d942-4115-af77-3f3035384d95, Duration=10644ms)

Portal:

Function App Logs:

2024-11-26T11:30:52Z   [Verbose]   Request successfully matched the route with name 'main' and template 'api/{*segments}'
2024-11-26T11:30:52Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.main' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=8166b9b2-02cd-47ee-bc22-26e3e7fa0b73)
2024-11-26T11:30:52Z   [Verbose]   Sending invocation id: '8166b9b2-02cd-47ee-bc22-26e3e7fa0b73
2024-11-26T11:30:52Z   [Verbose]   Posting invocation id:8166b9b2-02cd-47ee-bc22-26e3e7fa0b73 on workerId:5be600cb-2744-49c1-ba23-3f559eaa8401
2024-11-26T11:30:52Z   [Information]   Deamon awake -- Azure Function started ...
2024-11-26T11:30:52Z   [Information]   <html><h1>Controller alive and kicking ...Tue Nov 26 2024 11:30:51 GMT+0000</h1>
2024-11-26T11:30:52Z   [Information]    response constructed 
2024-11-26T11:31:02Z   [Information]   second time
2024-11-26T11:31:02Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.main' (Succeeded, Id=8166b9b2-02cd-47ee-bc22-26e3e7fa0b73, Duration=10011ms)


Thanks for your answer, may i ask how is it rendering in the browser .. do you see the first line "Controller alive and kicking" and then there is a delay of 10 seconds to get the next line ? For me Nestjs isnt sending a response as long as i am setting response.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked'); .. and without this it will wait for 10 secs to render all the content in one go.

Are you able to see Controller alive and kicking locally?
